# How to directly calculate a series of numbers and store them to a constexpr variable without calculating their size first at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, compile-time

Is there a way to avoid `get_primes_size`? Now the process of calculating primes less than 1000 is repeated twice.

Like first pushing them to a local `std::vector`, then turning it into a `std::array`?

```cpp
constexpr bool is_prime(int n)
{
    for (int i = 2; i * i < n; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

template <int upper_limit>
consteval int get_primes_size()
{
    int size = 0;
    for(int i = 2; i <= upper_limit; i++) {
        if (is_prime(i)) {
            size++;
        }
    }
    return size;
}

template <int upper_limit>
consteval auto get_primes()
{
    int count = 0;
    array<int, get_primes_size<upper_limit>()> primes;
    for(int i = 2; i <= upper_limit; i++) {
        if(is_prime(i)) {
            primes[count++] = i;
        }
    }
    return primes;
}

constexpr auto primes = get_primes<1000>();

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why not just return the vector? If you use it to calculate the primes anyway it's there already and it will be much easier to determine the return type of your function (if someone for whatever reason is not going to use `auto`). Otherwise I wouldn't care too much about calculating twice, it is done at compile time anyway (so you need longer time to compile) but won't effect the runtime of your programme.

Comment: Side note: `int` is not really the correct type for this kind of templates, rather use `size_t` instead.

Comment: Rewrite the constexprs a bit and you only have to calculate primes once. I use the [sieve method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) like this : https://onlinegdb.com/JA6YgmZEM

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be optimal but since there is for sure less than n/2 primes that are less than n you could just :

`array<int, upper_limit/2> primes;`

Than in your loop you keep count of the number of primes you encounter the same way you did in `get_prime_size` and return the truncated array.